# 13.04 i5 Temperature

Tags: 13.04, overheating, temperature, ivybridge

I'd have a fresh install of Ubuntu with tlp configured and using acpi_call to keep 7670M turned off.

I was a short time arch user and with openbox and firefox it was about 60 to 70 degrees; wanted to turn to a stable release just for this reason.

```
    acpitz-virtual-0
    Adapter: Virtual device
    temp1:        +50.0°C  

    radeon-pci-0100
    Adapter: PCI adapter
    temp1:       -128.0°C  

    coretemp-isa-0000
    Adapter: ISA adapter
    Physical id 0:  +56.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
    Core 0:         +54.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
    Core 1:         +55.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
```

The temperature is not seriously high yet can be lower.

Any suggestions?

Edit:

Surfing temps with one tab firefox:

```
    acpitz-virtual-0
    Adapter: Virtual device
    temp1:        +58.0°C  

    coretemp-isa-0000
    Adapter: ISA adapter
    Physical id 0:  +57.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
    Core 0:         +55.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
    Core 1:         +58.0°C  (high = +87.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
```

Edit 2: Using a simple linux game get highten it to 70.

Comment: Good questions, but can you separate them into separate question entries?  Too hard to answer in this form.

Comment: Install xfce instead of unity to disable the heavy use of compositing and your temp will drop.

Comment: 56 C is normal...what you can do is to use powersave on ac/bat with TLP, use indicator-cpufreq to change cpu frequency when you needed...use VA API if you are watching videos ( highly recommend ) ..http://askubuntu.com/questions/285434/is-there-a-power-saving-application-similar-to-jupiter/285681#285681

Comment: Agreed, this is a normal temp. You can set up CPU throttling that will keep you CPU as a set temp, maybe worth a look [Cool your CPU temperature with frequency throttling](http://seperohacker.blogspot.co.uk/2012/10/linux-keep-your-cpu-cool-with-frequency.html)

Comment: I'm using Gnome but that's not the question. CPU usage only differs about %1 to 2 between those DEs. I can agree that a degree of 56 can be considered normal but it is way too high for a computer that is running on a minimal installation without any process. What if use both cards on, that does make it go up to 70 to 80's. With official drivers and OS it is 35 to 40 at idle and as the reason of my question, there is great difference between a 105 and 90 degrees of celcius. PS.: I told that tlp is conf'ed already Keeping CPU as a set temp? That script would only enforce CPU without actual work.

Answer (score 0):

1. Run the command `sudo cp /etc/default/grub /etc/default/grub.backup`
2. Run the command `gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub`
3. Make sure you do not see noacpi (set it to acpi or delete it, depending on where it is), pci=noacpi (set it to pci=acpi), or acpi=off (set it to acpi=on)
4. Reboot and see if it helps.

Basically, you set Ubuntu to use acpi to control the hardware, which generally fixes overheating. If your computer does not boot, revert /etc/default/grub to /etc/default/grub.backup.

Comment: there is no acpi in grub.cfg and I think tlp handles what you mean by control, but since I use acpi call that however, I think is on too.